# How to rotate arbitrary degree an image

Tags: javascript

I want to rotate an image N degree
I write this code but it does not work what should I do?

```
var N=20
    function rotateImage() {
        var img = document.getElementById('myimage');
        img.style.transform = 'rotate(Ndeg)';

    }
```

and

```
img.style.transform = 'rotate(${N}deg)';
```

does not work but
    img.style.transform = 'rotate(20deg)';
works

Comment: Use string literal. replace: `'rotate(Ndeg)'` with `rotate(\`${N}deg\`)`

Comment: that does not work

Comment: @RandyCasburn "rotate" should also be part of the string. I think you wanted `img.style.transform = \`rotate(${N}deg)\`;`

Comment: @Joshua - yep..thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually place the variable into the string. You can either use a template literal (note the backticks,not single quotes), like so:

```
img.style.transform = `rotate(${N}deg)`;
```

Or, concatenate strings:

```
img.style.transform = 'rotate(' + N + 'deg)';
```

Also, I would refactor your code to take N as an argument:

```
function rotateImage(N) {
    var img = document.getElementById('myimage');
    img.style.transform = 'rotate(' + N + ')';

}
rotateImage(20);
```

---

Or, if it is really always by 20 degrees:

```
function rotateImage() {
    document.getElementById('myimage').style.transform = 'rotate(20deg)';
}
```

Comment: I want to 20deg rotate by every click.what shoul I add to your code?

Comment: Then you could just use your original function but use the full string `'rotate(20deg)'`. Updated answer to show simplified function.

Comment: Or if you really mean by an **additional** 20 degrees (so second click becomes 40 degrees, third click 60), it would be something like `img.style.transform = 'rotate(' + (parseInt(/(\d+)deg/.exec(img.style.transform)[1],10)+20) + 'deg)';`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var N=100;
    function rotate () {
        var img = document.getElementById('myimage');
        img.style.transform = 'rotate( '+N+'deg)';
    }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbLrE.png" i id="myimage" onclick="rotate ();" />
```